# Kivy, ScrollView scrolls automatically when contents change size

Tags: python, kivy

I have a GridLayout inside of a ScrollView. The GridLayout contains about 25 images. The images are chosen at runtime so their sizes cannot be determined beforehand. These images are loaded asynchronously at different times ( there is at least a 500 millisecond difference between them ).

The problem occurs when the image is loaded and the size of the GridLayout changes. From what I understand, the ScrollView's `scroll_y` is set to some value relative to the original height of the GridLayout. Then, once the image has loaded the size of the GridLayout changes, but the `scroll_y` is still relative to the old height. This causes the ScrollView to scroll down by a large amount.

I've tried to rectify this by manually changing the `scroll_y` to match the new height. I'm using the following equation:

[Equation for Finding New Scroll_Y](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?(1&space;-&space;y_i)&space;*&space;h_i&space;=&space;(1-&space;y_f)&space;*&space;h_f)

I'm subracting `scroll_y` from 1 because a scroll value of 1 is at the very top in kivy. I've reordered this equation to the following and have implemented this in code:

[Simplified Equation for Finding New Scroll_Y](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?y_f&space;=&space;%5Cfrac%7B(y-1)*h_i%7D%7Bh_f%7D&space;+&space;1)

This has reduced the problem, and there is a less apparent jittering, but it still scrolls up by 5-10 pixels each time an image is loaded.

This is because I'm calculating the new height for the equation, based on:

- the old viewport height of the ScrollView
- the old height of the image widget
- the new height of the image.

But, this calculated height is slightly bigger than what the actual height turns out to be, causing my adjusted `scroll_y` to be slightly off. I'm not sure why the actual height is smaller.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Here is a link to a repository that has a minimal reproducible example. [Grid Stuttering Example](https://github.com/teststhrowaway/GridStuttering)

Comment: You are not likely to get any help on a question like this without providing a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my question to include one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to do what you want is to extend `ScrollView`. Here is a class extending `ScrollView` that does what you want:

```
class ScrollViewNoStutter(ScrollView):
    child_height = NumericProperty(0)

    def add_widget(self, widget, index=0):
        super(ScrollViewNoStutter, self).add_widget(widget, index=index)
        widget.bind(size=self.child_size_changed)

    def remove_widget(self, widget):
        super(ScrollViewNoStutter, self).remove_widget(widget)
        widget.unbind(size=self.child_size_changed)

    def child_size_changed(self, child, new_child_size):
        if new_child_size[1] > self.size[1]:
            # re-calculate scroll_y

            # calculate distance between scrollview top and child top (in pixels)
            y_dist = (1.0 - self.scroll_y) * (self.child_height - self.height)

            # calculate new scroll_y that reproduces the above distance
            self.scroll_y = 1.0 - y_dist / (new_child_size[1] - self.height)

        self.child_height = new_child_size[1]
```

Just use this class in place of `ScrollView`, and you won't need any of those calculations in your `App`.